# Java JAR Couldn't find main class

Tags: java, jar

64x Intel processor
Kubuntu 19.04 on Linux 5.0.0-27
OpenJDK 1.8.0_222

---

In the last hour I have set up my project folder, created scripts for automatic compiling and for back-ups etc...

Finally I got it working, I get the JAR file. The problem is that I can't run it. I know that this is very common problem, but I don't see any compiling errors, mistakes nor typos. I'm totally lost.

Even using `java -jar TaskCalender.jar com.ydsoftware.taskcalender.EntryPoint` and `java -cp TaskCalender.jar com.ydsoftware.taskcalender.EntryPoint` show the same error.

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ydsoftware.taskcalender.EntryPoint
```

My source file structure:

```
com
  ydsoftware
    taskcalender
      EntryPoint.java (contains main method)
```

My JAR file structure:

```
META-INF
  MANIFEST.MF 
com
  ydsoftware
    taskcalender
      EntryPoint.class (contains main method)
```

MANIFEST.MF contents (inside the JAR file):

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_222 (Private Build)
Main-Class: com.ydsoftware.taskcalender.EntryPoint
Class-Path: lib/MX%20Engine.jar
/ blank /
/ blank /
```

Comment: if using `java -jar` the main class must be specified in the [JAR Manifest](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#jar-manifest) (inside the JAR); (if using `java -cp` it is specified in the command line, as you are trying)

Comment: How did you generate your jar file. Are you able to execute the class without creating jar?

Comment: after question edit: what happens if you try `java -cp TaskCalendar.jar com.ydsoftware.taskcalender.EntryPoint`? Also what is the output of `java -version`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The manifest contents are shown and it point to the correct main class.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The output of `java -version` is `openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~19.04.1-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
`

Comment: @SujayMohan The JAR file create using  `jar -cfmv ../TaskCalender.jar ../MANIFEST.MF .`. I will try to run the class itself indepentently.

Comment: it cannot be (only) the manifest, using `-cp` does not need it - it must be something wrong with the class file (name/folder with *strange* character) or loading of class (external library/dependency??? missing some error for that) - maybe trying with `java -cp . com.ydsoftware.taskcalender.EntryPoint` (non-jar version)

Comment: I will try to simplify the class, I will remove all imports and I will make it just say Hello World. I will keep everything else.

Comment: For some weird reason, it worked? The problem is probably the library. The code compiles which means it finds the library. I will look into that.

Comment: If you are able to run the class individually you should be able to run it from jar also.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see why it's better to do, thank you, I will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below in CMD or through batch file as per your convenience

Generic:
java -cp your_jar_name.jar package_name.classname

as per your class:
java -cp TaskCalender.jar com.ydsoftware.taskcalender.EntryPoint

Comment: Forgot to add that this doesn't work either. Thank you for trying!

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

The problem was that `Class-Path: lib/MX%20Engine.jar` was missing because my computer had shut down unexpectably (because our power was cut off for some reason) and the changes to MANIFEST.MF were lost. Didn't even notice.

Still, it should say something along the lines of `Class not found` or `unexcepted token` instead of saying `Could not find or load main class` which  made finding the problem harder.

Thank you to everyone who tried to help me!